# \pgfmathveclen{x}{y}

Tags: pgfmath

i need the length between Y and Z later.
I hoped that would work, but doesn't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Koordinaten
    \coordinate (A) at (1,-3);
    \coordinate (B) at (8,1);
    \coordinate (C) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (D) at (8,4);
    \coordinate (E) at (6,-4);
    \coordinate (F) at (6,4);
    
    % Strecken
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, name path = a] (A) --  node[midway, below right]{a} (B);
    \draw[line width=1.5pt,name path = b] (C) -- node[midway, below right] {b} (D);
    \draw[line width=1.5pt,name path = c] (E) -- node[near end, right] {c} (F);
    
    % Finde die Schnittpunkte
    % a und c
    \path[name intersections={of=a and c, by={Z}}];
    % b und c
    \path[name intersections={of=b and c, by={Y}}];
    
    % Berechne die Länge der Strecke YZ
    \pgfmathveclen{\x1}{\y1}
    \edef\lengthZY{\pgfmathresult}
    
    % Ausgabe der Länge
    \draw (Y) -- (Z) node[midway, above] {\(\lengthZY\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help
Patrick

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't compile, you need the tikz librairies `intersections` and `calc`.

```tex
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc}
```

Furthermore, `\x1` and `\y1` are defined by the `let` path operation. This should work :

```tex
\draw   let \p1=(Y), \p2=(Z), \n1 = {veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in
    (Y) -- (Z)  node[midway, above] {\n1};
```

Full code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Koordinaten
    \coordinate (A) at (1,-3);
    \coordinate (B) at (8,1);
    \coordinate (C) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (D) at (8,4);
    \coordinate (E) at (6,-4);
    \coordinate (F) at (6,4);

    % Strecken
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, name path = a] (A) --  node[midway, below right]{a} (B);
    \draw[line width=1.5pt,name path = b] (C) -- node[midway, below right] {b} (D);
    \draw[line width=1.5pt,name path = c] (E) -- node[near end, right] {c} (F);

    % Finde die Schnittpunkte
    % a und c
    \path[name intersections={of=a and c, by={Z}}];
    % b und c
    \path[name intersections={of=b and c, by={Y}}];

    % Berechne die Länge der Strecke YZ
    % Ausgabe der Länge
    \draw   let \p1=(Y), \p2=(Z), \n1 = {veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in
    (Y) -- (Z)  node[midway, above] {\n1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

In the `pgfmanual` documentation section 4.1.3 The Circle Around A we can read:

> The only remaining problem is to access the x- and y-coordinate of the
> vector AB. For this, we need a new concept: the let operation

We can, as jlab did, use 2 points `\p1` and `\p2`, we can also use the vector `\p1` (YZ) and use `\pgfmathveclen` as in your post.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Koordinaten
    \coordinate (A) at (1,-3);
    \coordinate (B) at (8,1);
    \coordinate (C) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (D) at (8,4);
    \coordinate (E) at (6,-4);
    \coordinate (F) at (6,4);
    
    % Strecken
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, name path = a] (A) --  node[midway, below right]{a} (B);
    \draw[line width=1.5pt,name path = b] (C) -- node[midway, below right] {b} (D);
    \draw[line width=1.5pt,name path = c] (E) -- node[near end, right] {c} (F);
    
    % Finde die Schnittpunkte
    % a und c
    \path[name intersections={of=a and c, by={Z}}];
    % b und c
    \path[name intersections={of=b and c, by={Y}}];
    % Ausgabe der Länge
    \draw (Y) -- (Z) let
        \p1=($(Z) - (Y)$)
        in
        node[midway,right] {$\pgfmathveclen{\x1}{\y1}\pgfmathresult$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: with the package `tkz-euclide`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Koordinaten
    \tkzDefPoints{1/-3/A,8/1/B,1/0/C,8/4/D,6/-4/E,6/4/F}
    % \coordinate (A) at (1,-3);
    % \coordinate (B) at (8,1);
    % \coordinate (C) at (1,0);
    % \coordinate (D) at (8,4);
    % \coordinate (E) at (6,-4);
    % \coordinate (F) at (6,4);
    
    % Strecken
    \tkzDrawLines[line width=1.5pt](A,B C,D E,F)
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.3,below right](A,B){$a$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=0.3,below right](C,D){$b$}
    \tkzLabelLine[pos=1.1,below right](E,F){$c$}
    % \draw[line width=1.5pt, name path = a] (A) --  node[midway, below right]{a} (B);
    % \draw[line width=1.5pt,name path = b] (C) -- node[midway, below right] {b} (D);
    % \draw[line width=1.5pt,name path = c] (E) -- node[near end, right] {c} (F);
    
    % Finde die Schnittpunkte
    % a und c
    \tkzInterLL(A,B)(E,F) \tkzGetPoint{Z}
    % \path[name intersections={of=a and c, by={Z}}];
    % % b und c
    \tkzInterLL(C,D)(E,F) \tkzGetPoint{Y}
    %\tkzLabelPoints(A,...,F,Z,Y)
    % \path[name intersections={of=b and c, by={Y}}];
    % Ausgabe der Länge
    \tkzCalcLength(Y,Z)\tkzGetLength{YZ}
    \tkzLabelSegment[right](Y,Z){$\pgfmathprintnumber{\YZ}$\ cm}
    % \draw (Y) -- (Z) let
    %     \p1=($(Z) - (Y)$)
    %     in
    %     node[midway,right] {$\pgfmathveclen{\x1}{\y1}\pgfmathresult$};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \tkzMarkAngle(C,Y,Z)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, did not read the right chapter.
No i try to draw a part of a circle. Therefore i made a circle path an found the intersection.
I tried to draw a circle and could not handle, instead i draw an angle:
\draw let \p1=(Y), \p2=(Z), \n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in pic[draw=black,-,  line width=1, angle radius=\n1] {angle=Y--Z--Z2}; 
This works finde, but how to draw it as a circle.

Comment: @Patrick, The `tkz-euclide` package may interest you. I edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here a version with TikZ and tkz-elements. The intersections of the lines are obtained naturally after creating the L.AB, L.CD and L.EF objects. The length of the YZ segment is then obtained either in Lua or in TikZ. The length function is used to obtain this length. The TikZ macro \tkzDN is used to format a number. `\tkzUseLua` allows you to use  tkz-elements: `length(z.Y,z.Z`.

```
with lualatex !!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-elements}
\begin{document}
  
\begin{tkzelements}
  z.A  = point : new (1,-3)
  z.B  = point : new  (8,1)
  z.C  = point : new  (1,0)
  z.D  = point : new  (8,4)
  z.E  = point : new  (6,-4)
  z.F  = point : new  (6,4)
  L.AB = line  : new (z.A,z.B)
  L.CD = line  : new (z.C,z.D)
  L.EF = line  : new (z.E,z.F)
  z.Z  = intersection (L.AB,L.EF)
  z.Y  = intersection (L.CD,L.EF)
\end{tkzelements}
  
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzGetNodes
  \draw[line width=1.5pt] (A) -- node[midway, below right]{a} (B);
  \draw[line width=1.5pt] (C) -- node[midway, below right] {b} (D);
  \draw[line width=1.5pt] (E) -- node[near end, right] {c} (F);
  \path  (Y) -- (Z)  node[midway,right]         {\tkzDN{\tkzUseLua{length(z.Y,z.Z)}}};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

If instead of  `z.E  = point : new  (6,-4)' we use` z.E = point: new  (3,-4)` we get : (without modifying anything)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try both examples later. No time now.

Comment: Thanks, i use Lualatex, but it does not compile.
"File ended while scanning use of \luacode@grab@lines."

Comment: @Patrick   What version of tkz-elements are you using? Can you send me your .log file and your main file? (email on the doc) Possible syntax error